# Choices validation in WTForms does not update when database does

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, py2neo

I understand the `SelectField` method in WTForms takes can argument `choices` which has the form...

```
choices=[("value1", "display of value 1"), ("value2", "display of value 2")]
```

I need to populate my choices based on a call to the database.  I'm using neo4j as my backend, so I can't use modelforms or the other built-in solutions for populating data in a form.

```
def get_list_of_things():
    query = 'start n = node:things("*:*") return ID(n), n.display_name;'
    t = cypher.execute(cdb, query)[0]
    for x in t:
        x[0] = str(x[0])
        x[1] = str(x[1])
    things = list(tuple(x) for x in t)
    return things

class SelectAThing(Form):
    thingID = SelectField('Thing name', choices=get_list_of_things())
```

Running choices = get_list_of_things() does produce a valid list of choices, great, and this basically works.

However, it doesn't ever seem to update the list of things even when the database does and I return to that form later.  If I add things to the db and return, I still see the first list of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No dummy, just don't put it in the class.  Put it in the view code.

```
@app.route('/route')
def routename()
    form = SelectAThing()
    form.orgid.choices=get_joinable_orgs()
```

I found this tricky because I didn't realize I could assign to form like it was a regular python object after initializing it in the view.

Answer (score 7):

Yup - you got it. WTForms is a little unintuitive that way.

By the way, if you're pulling choices out of a SQLAlchemy database (and you're using Flask), check out the QuerySelectField addon:

http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

def all_employees():
  return Employee.query

class BugReportForm(Form):
  description = TextField(u"Notes")
  # The get_label will show the "name" attribute of the Employee model
  assign_to = QuerySelectField(u'Assign to',
                           get_label=u"name",
                           query_factory=all_employees)
```

That'll give you a Select field with the names of everybody.

Bonus: when you access BugReportForm.assign_to.data in the view code, it'll return the Employee object (not the id). It's handy.

Comment: That is super useful.  I wish sqlalchemy supported neo4j so I could use this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried QuerySelectField but because it is not "select input" and it is a ul element, it can't accept events like onchange and hard to get the value with JavaScript, so I have to keep the selectField field, and since it's not a custom path and this is modal View , I updated kawargs['form'].column.choices inside the render function and turn of the validation for selectField to accept updated streets without reloading the application

```
form_extra_fields = {
    'streetname': SelectField(
        'streetname',
        coerce=str,
        choices=([street.streetname for street in db.session.query(StreetsMetadata).all()]),
        render_kw={'onchange': "myFunction()"},
        validate_choice=False
        ),
    }

def render(self, template, **kwargs):
    """
    using extra js in render method allow use
    url_for that itself requires an app context
    """
    # solved By Python King
    if 'form' in kwargs and 'streetname' in kwargs['form'] and 'choices' in vars(kwargs['form'].streetname):
        kwargs['form'].streetname.choices = [street.streetname for street in db.session.query(StreetsMetadata).all()]
    self.extra_js = [url_for("static", filename="admin/js/users.js")]
    response = render_miror(self, template, **kwargs)
    return response
```