# Flask wtform cached dynamic select field?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a problem with my form, so basically I have a `SelectField` dynamically loaded from database query, and everytime I did an operation to the database, it seems like the `SelectField` is not updated and following the realtime value in the database.

so here is my code `view.py`

```
@app.route('/add/sale-transaction', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_sale_transaction():
    form = forms.ItemSaleForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # get unsold items to be added so I can mark it sold
        items = models.Item.query.join(models.PurchaseTransaction) \
            .filter((models.Item.sale_transaction_id == None) & (models.Item.item_type_id == form.item_stock.data)) \
            .order_by(models.PurchaseTransaction.transaction_date) \
            .order_by(models.Item.id) \
            .limit(form.quantity.data)

        # for each item add sale transaction field to mark it sold
        for it in items:
            it.sale_price = form.sale_price.data
            it.sale_transaction_id = # something here..
            db.session.add(it)
            db.session.flush()

        db.session.commit()
        flash('Successfuly added new Sale Transaction')
        return redirect(request.path)

    return render_template('add-sale-transaction.html', form=form)
```

then in my `form.py`

```
class ItemSaleForm(wtforms.Form):
    sale_price = IntegerField(label='Sale Price: ',
                              validators=[InputRequired()])

    # get unsold items and its quantity
    unsold_items = db.session.query(models.Item.item_type_id, models.ItemType.item_type, func.count(models.Item.id)) \
        .join(models.ItemType) \
        .filter(models.Item.sale_transaction_id == None) \
        .group_by(models.Item.item_type_id)

    # convert to dict to be used by SelectField
    qty_separator = ' - qty: '
    unsold_items_dict = {}
    for item in unsold_items:
        unsold_items_dict[item[0]] = '{}{}{}'.format(item[1], qty_separator, item[2])

    item_stock = SelectField(label='Item Type: ',
                             coerce=int,
                             choices=unsold_items_dict.items(),
                             validators=[InputRequired()])
    quantity = IntegerField(label='Item Quantity',
                            validators=[InputRequired()])
```

Here is the explanation, if I access `/add/sale-transaction` and fill in the form, in the field `item_stock` (`SelectField`) it should give me the list of **unsold items** - item which has no `sale_transaction_id` and no `sale_price` - and show its own `quantity`.

So after I submit the form, obviously some changes happen to list of **unsold items**, but apparently the `SelectField choices=` does not change, it still has same value as before.

If I do a manual query after submitting the form, I can see changes in **unsold items**, so I'm suspecting either the `db.session` expiry/refresh or `form` is not recreated during request to '/add/sale-transaction' or maybe the wtform cache something..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problems, turns out it is the wtforms that behaves a bit weird with `choices` attribute for the `SelectField`. I found some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781616/choices-validation-in-wtforms-does-not-update-when-database-does), and it solves my problem if I declare `choice` either in the `__init__()` or `view`